# Can someone tell me how I can paste Mathematica code into a message here without losing the math formatting

Tags: discussion

Thanks in advance.  There is a sizable chunk of code would like some help with.  But I need to understand how to paste it in here properly.

Comment: Related: [What kind of Input and Output Code Styles are acceptable in SE?](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1027/4330), [How do I cut/paste Mathematica output into a question (duplicate)](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1416/4330) and [this answer](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/6/4330)

Answer (score 3):

If I interpret your question correctly you want to include "2D" formatted *Mathematica* code in a post.  The Stack Exchange software does not support this.  The main site (but not this Meta) does support LaTeX but generally that should not be used for code or other expressions that are intended to be pasted into *Mathematica*.  ([Posting equations as LaTeX or Mathematica code](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/35/121).)

To share code I suggest that, after saving your work or making a copy of the Notebook, you select the Cell(s) you wish to post then use menu **Cell** > **Convert To** > **InputForm** or the equivalent keyboard shortcut.  That turn something like this:

[image]

Into:

[image]

You should then be able to copy the content and paste it as plain code, e.g.:

```
Sum[1/(j^2*(i + 1)^2), {i, 1, Infinity}, {j, 1, i}]
```

Comment: Thank you for your very clear answer!  I find that this site does not explain the very easy basic stuff for those new to posting to this newsgroup.

Comment: @Phillip I am you found this answer useful.  This Meta site exists to answer questions such as these.  Note that this is note a newsgroup in the sense I am familiar with the term; please see the [tour].